# Retrieving Author ID in wp-admin area

Tags: php, posts, wp-admin, author

Currently able to display the post author ID on the frontend with no difficulties. Returning the ID in /wp-admin when editing a post is proving to be tricky. Here's what I have so far:

```
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id(); // Get the current users ID
$author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $post_id); // Get the author ID

if( is_user_logged_in() && $current_user_id == $author_id ) { 
    // wp-dashboard script
}
```

I've tried a handful of other methods for getting the user ID with no success. Displaying $current_user_id through the theme's functions.php file worked without issues along with other PHP code. Perhaps the ID isn't being loaded when functions.php loads?

Comment: In which action hook you are trying to do this?

Comment: I think you don't need to use is_user_logged_in() because get_current_user_id() return 0 for non logged in user.

Comment: I should have clarified that I'm using this for the plugin co-authors plus so that I can allow authors to assign other authors. After placing an edit_cap filter: https://github.com/Automattic/Co-Authors-Plus/issues/104#issuecomment-317110969
The problem was that co-authors could take over a given post from the original author. As a result I needed a way to have the add_filter to execute only if the page author is viewing the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this without having to rely on the $post global.

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    if( isset( $_GET['post'] ) && isset( $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] === 'edit' ) {
        $post_id = $_GET['post'];
        $current_post = get_post($post_id);
        $author_id = $current_post->post_author;
    } 
}
```

The query string variable `post` is always the `post_id` you are editing and additionally you need to check if the `action` query variable is set and it equals to `edit`.

Additionally you can explore the [get_current_screen()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) function to setup more advanced conditionals for better security.